# Howto Get application port through MXBean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

given a application: http://localhost:8080/myapp/

is it possible to enquire JVM through MBean/MXBean in which port the current application code is accepting requests? and also the appcontext (myapp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I answer it :)

Since Application Server MXBEans are plataform dependent - each vendor export the AS features they want - my solution was to capture this information in the traditional way, through servlet request.

that's it.